# How to solve a 1-D wave equation when given no boundary/initial conditions on $x$?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, boundary-value-problem, wave-equation, initial-value-problems

So I'm looking at a wave equation defined by $$u_{tt} = c^2 u_{xx}$$ for $-\pi < x < \pi$
with the following conditions:
$u(x,0) = (|x|-\pi)^2$, and $u_t(x,0) = 0$

I'm trying to use both separation of variables, and d'alembert's method, but I keep getting stuck? Without the conditions on $x$, with SoV, I can't get any solutions to $\lambda = 0$, so I'm not sure where to go from there.

While using d'Alembert's method, I've arrived at expressions for $u(x,0) = \phi(x) + \psi(x)$ and $u_t(x,0) = c(\phi'(x) - \psi'(x))$, but I'm not sure how to equate them or get a solution out of them.

Are there any other methods that can be used? Or are these ones usable in this case? I would appreciate any help at all! Just need to get over this confusion for now.

(p.s. I can send a picture of my working up until now if anyone can/wants to take a look at it, but I will not be typing it out here since it is quite lengthy).

Comment: No boundary conditions are needed, in fact. Just the initial data $u(x,0)$, $(\partial_t u)(x,0)$ is sufficient to get a unique solution. Remember that letting $u_0(x)=u(x,0)$, $\dot{u}_0(x)=\partial_tu(x,0)$ that
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\left(u_0(x-ct)+u_0(x+ct)\right)+\frac{1}{2c}\int\limits_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\dot{u}_0(s)\mathrm ds$$
Make sure to do your integrals right and the correct answer should pop out.

Comment: Ohh hmm. Interesting. Okay so I'll try it again, and see if it works. Otherwise, can I comment here again/send a chat and ask for clarification?

Comment: Yes, I will be notified of comments on this question.

Comment: Alright, perfect. So I'm looking at it again, and I think I will mention that the conditions are $u(x,t=0) = (|x|-\pi)^2$, and $u_t(x,0) = 0$. Even in this case, especially with $u_0$ and $u_0'$ at $t=0$, should I be using $u_0(x \pm ct)$ and the $x \pm ct$ limits in the integral? Could you explain why? Should I not just insert the equations as I have them? (i.e. for example, $\frac{1}{2}((|x|-\pi)^2 + (|x|-\pi)^2)$ and then also integrate 0 wrt s)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm finding your last comment a little hard to understand, so I will just demonstrate the solution below. We have the initial data
$$u(x,0)=u_0(x)=(|x|-\pi)^2 \\ (\partial_tu)(x,0)=\dot{u}_0(x)=0$$
So,
$$u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\big(u_0(x-ct)+u_0(x+ct)\big)+\frac{1}{2c}\int\limits_{x-ct}^{x+ct}\dot{u}_0(s)\mathrm ds \\ u(x,t)=\frac{1}{2}\big((|x-ct|-\pi)^2+(|x+ct|-\pi)^2\big)$$
Because integrating zero gives you zero. One can find that this solution actually unbounded, in other words it is non-physical. In order to get a physical solution, one would need to drop the initial condition $(\partial_tu)(x,0)=0$ and replace it with the boundary conditions
$$u(-\pi,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$$
And this would require a different solution method, most likely using S.O.V and Sturm-Liouville theory.

Comment: Ahh okay okay. Sorry for the other comment not making that much sense lol, but this answer pretty much cleared most of it up so it's all good! Hopefully just one more question though. Does the fact that $-\pi < x < \pi$ account for anything in this question though? Is it being used anywhere/should it be?  Also, just to confirm, an unbounded solution means that it doesn't really converge to anything, right?

Comment: @Applesauce44 Unbounded means we can make $|u(x,t)|$ arbitrarily large. The fact the equation is being solved in $[-\pi,\pi]$ doesn't make any difference here.

Comment: Ahh alright, thank you! This was helpful!